# Parse Server "Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server, passport.js

Me and my partner are having serious issues with MongoDB these days. Suddenly, our Parse Server mounted on MongoDB, in a VPS, started failing. Our app couldn't connect there, nor the Parse Dashboard. Something was failing.

In the parse logs, this is what appears:

> {"level":"info","message":"Parse LiveQuery Server starts
>   running","timestamp":"2017-07-09T20:23:59.711Z"}
>   {"level":"info","message":"Parse LiveQuery Server starts
>   running","timestamp":"2017-07-09T20:25:47.884Z"} {"message":"Unable to
>   ensure uniqueness for usernames:
>   ","name":"MongoError","stack":"MongoError: failed to connect to server
>   [localhost:27017] on first connect\n    at null.
>   (/home/main/StepApp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/$ {"message":"Unable
>   to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses:
>   ","name":"MongoError","stack":"MongoError: failed to connect to server
>   [localhost:27017] on first connect\n    at null.
>   (/home/main/StepApp/node_modules/mongod$

We tried this whole bunch of things:

- Installing a new MongoDB version
- Import the old .db files
- Restart our Node.js instancies via pm2
- Adding more space to our VPS (it seems MongoDB was having some trouble with disk space, but this is already fixed).
- Adding an admin user to our db, with all permissions, and then adding it to the mongodb connection string in our Node file.
- After all of this, several server restarts, pm2 restarts, mongo restarts...

... nothing works.

When I restart the server, I receive that strange error string I copied before, though Mongo is working fine.

Seems to be more of a Parse problem... but, why?

Any help will he appreciated!

**EDIT / UPDATE:**
I've been checking if MongoDB is working, and it's service "mongod" is online. Tried to listen to a different port, changed it too in the index.js mongo connection string, but I keep getting the same error.

Strange thing is, that when I connect to my database with my newly created Mongo user, it authenticates correctly! (I could see it in the logs). So it seems to be a Parse error, somehow it doesn't get the Mongo response or something like that.

What do you think?

Comment: do you have 2 records in your user collections which have the username set as the same?

Comment: @andrew.butkus nope, we had 3 test users with different names. Anyways, I'm accessing to the mongo terminal, show the collections with "show collections" inside the DB, and then when I try to do db._Users.find(), it shows an error saying that it's undefined, and it happens with every collection that starts with underscore. Why is this?

Comment: `MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]` is the most important part of the error message. The error you are quoting actually comes from the passport middle-ware. But the **reason** is the MongoDB connection cannot be made. Being either: 1. Not running 2. Not at that address.  Given that you are poking around in a directory named `/home/main/StepApp/node_modules/mongod` then your installation looks suspect. It really is shockingly bad practice to run your application and database on the same server and you really should reconsider your deployment.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for the answer, but this is just for testing purposes! Our application is not in production yet, that's why we've set the backend and the DB in the same server. It used to work perfectly fine until now, things be said. What do you think may be causing this?

Comment: MONGODB IS NOT RUNNING OR REACHABLE. Please actually read things.

Comment: @NeilLunn It is running. The service is online, and it even authenticates correctly the user I created, when one of my instances are restarted. So it's like if Node is able to connect to Mongo, but somehow, Mongo isn't able to send back info to Node, so Parse throws this error. The logs show that mongo is working, and "service mongod status" output is "online" in the same port I access from my Node file.

Comment: do a `gitk --follow index.js` and see if you changed something to do with the database.